# property decleared at service doesn't reflecting in view

Tags: angular

I use a service where I have these:

```
export class GamePlayService {

  bigBlind:number=20;
  
  players=[{name:'Cpu Player',chips:this.startingChips,isDealer:true,isBigBlind:false,isSmallBlind:false,isActivePlayer:false,bettingAmount:0,temporaryBetting:0},
  {name:'Me',chips:this.startingChips,isDealer:false,isBigBlind:false,isSmallBlind:false,isActivePlayer:true,bettingAmount:0,temporaryBetting:0},
  ];
  
  temporaryRaise:number=this.bigBlind + this.players[0].bettingAmount;

  constructor() { }

  raise(ref:any){
    this.players[1].bettingAmount+=parseInt(ref);  
  }
```

After that another function from another service runs

```
raiseCpu(){
  this.game.players[0].bettingAmount+=this.game.players[1].bettingAmount*3;
}
```

After these a string interpolation that there is at app.component.html doesnt updates.
`{{this.gamePlay.temporaryRaise}}`

Can you give me a reason why it doesnt work, but this works?
`{{this.gamePlay.players[0].bettingAmount+this.gamePlay.bigBlind}}`

From DOM the ref of raise() is for example 50, after that raiseCpu() runs(from another service) and places a 3bet .After these changes the temporaryRaise didn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

1. This code doesn't actually do anything:

```
raiseCpu(){
  this.game.players[0].bettingAmount += this.game.players[1].bettingAmount * 3;
}
```

That's because `players[1].bettingAmount` equals zero and 0 * 3 is still zero. So you're doing basically `this.game.players[0].bettingAmount += 0`.

For your tests to have some visible changes, start with `this.players[0].bettingAmount` having a value greater than 0.

2. Secondly, a simple class field (regardless if it's in a service or not), does not get re-evaluated at the change detection of a component. It needs to be a method or getter in the service in order to be re-evaluated. Something like this:

change from this:

`temporaryRaise:number=this.bigBlind + this.players[0].bettingAmount;`

to this:

`get temporaryRaise() { return this.bigBlind + this.players[0].bettingAmount };`

---

With these two changes, it should start working. Check it out here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqgefj?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Thank you !! My code works well.(i didn't wrote all the logic because  its too much). I just wanted to show the problem. I tried getter some time ago but i had typo error.. Your suggestion works perfect!!! So your answer is my solution!